# What does "three tracks with bundles are needed to orient the floor" mean?

Tags: tracking, video

I have selected few tracks on the floor (three or more) and press the *Floor* button. As a result I get the following message:

> Three tracks with bundles are needed to orient the floor

What does it mean? What is "with bundles"? What are "bundles"?

**UPDATE**

Below is an example. Five tracks are selected, all of them are of same color. How can I see that some of them has no "bundles"? I was pressing "Solve Camera..." button before.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "on the flow".

Answer (score 8):

In order to create the floor you have to **solve the clip first**. **bundles** are basically **solve data** for the track. Your error is probably caused by unsolved/incorrectly solved tracks.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking):

> **Bundles** makes sense after solving the movie clip, and it works in the following way: the solved position of each track gets projected
>   back to the movie clip and displayed as a small point. The color of
>   the point depends on the distance between the projected coordinate and
>   the original coordinate: if they are close enough, the point is green,
>   otherwise it'll be red. This helps to find tracks which weren't solved
>   nicely and need to be tweaked.

Comment: What is "solve the clip"?

Comment: @Dims When you solve fore camera motion. If you don't know how to do that, find a tutorial.

Comment: @Dims Here's the documentation for motion tracking: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I just didn't knew that "solving clip" is the same as "solving camera".

Answer (score 4):

**It simply means you didn't clicked on solve button after tracking your video**

[image]

**steps to have a clean track**

1. Track points on your video
2. Highlight all track markers or your points by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
3. Now click on Solve camera. Aim to get an error below 0.3 pixels, else refine you tracking.
4. Now click on the center most point and click Set origin

[image]

5. deselect the point and now select 3 points that are your floor and click on "Floor".
6. Now first click on Set as Background and lastly click on setup Tracking Scene.

For more tips on tracking read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42332

Comment: This answer is the most clear and concise motion tracking tutorial I have ever seen!