# What is the pixel error in motion tracking?

Tags: tracking

When 3D tracking, you have a pixel error. Is that error the number of pixels the track will stray with each frame, or the entire track?

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question with an image of the error you are having. What are you doing that is causing it?

Comment: Given your current interest in tracking you should take some time and watch Sebastian Koenig's series on motion tracking called "track, match, blend". It will save you (and us) a lot of time.

Comment: Also read the long post on this site: **[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)**

Answer (score 2):

The [re-projection error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reprojection_error) is the difference in pixels between where the tracker is placing a point in the image, and where it is being re-projected in the geometry when the scene is **Solved**.

In the perfect world there should be no error, but in the real world there is usually some degree of discrepancy, given the nature of trackers, optics, and user error.

Usually tracking is considered accurate when the re-projection error is less than 1/3 of a pixel (0.3 pixels).

[image]

[image]

**The number is always an average**.

You can see the average per tracker (for however many frames the tracker is active) in the dopesheet

[image]

Or you get a report of the average of all bundled tracks for the whole scene at the bottom of the page.

[image]

[How to see bundles and back projecting points of different colors?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13663/how-to-see-bundles-and-back-projecting-points-of-different-colors/13670#13670)

and

[Single track with bundle should be selected to define axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170357/single-track-with-bundle-should-be-selected-to-define-axis/194151#194151)

[Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful/14331#14331)